# How to populate new column by comparing one row with its next row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am finding difficulty in writing a query  to get the desired output.
I need to get date difference between two consecutive rows and If date difference is <=6 months and reason code is valid "Yes" Then new column should be populate with values "Yes" other wise "NO"

I have to populate new column with values "Yes" or "NO" based on criteria given below
**Criteria 1**:
For first row, New column value should be always "No"
From second row, If two dates difference is <=6 moths and reason code is valid then new column value should be "Yes" other wise "No"
Date difference of first row and second row is <=6 months and code valid "yes" hence new column value is Yes.
Date diff of second row and third row is <=6 months but valid is "No" hence new column value is "No".
Date diff of third row and forth row is more than >6 months and but valid is "Yes" hence new column value is "No".
Out put should be like below

| Custid | enter_date | Rscode | Valid | New_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-04-11 | BCB | Yes | No |
| 123 | 2020-06-13 | ABC | Yes | Yes |
| 123 | 2020-09-01 | FBS | No | No |
| 123 | 2021-05-01 | ABC | Yes | NO |
| 123 | 2021-07-05 | ABC | Yes | Yes |

**Criteria 2:**
If reason code is starts with "RQT" and any of the valid code is followed By RQT(even date difference is 6 months and reason code is valid) then new column should be "No" from next consecutive row, the output is same as is.

| Custid | enter_date | Rscode | Valid | New_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 2020-02-19 | RQT | Yes | NO |
| 345 | 2020-03-22 | BCB | Yes | NO |
| 345 | 2020-06-18 | RQT | Yes | Yes |
| 345 | 2020-10-29 | BCB | Yes | Yes |
| 345 | 2021-03-24 | ABC | Yes | Yes |

| Custid | enter_date | Rscode | Valid | New_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 346 | 2020-02-19 | RQT | Yes | NO |
| 346 | 2020-03-22 | RQT | Yes | NO |
| 346 | 2020-06-18 | RQT | Yes | Yes |
| 346 | 2020-10-29 | BCB | Yes | Yes |
| 346 | 2021-03-24 | RQT | Yes | Yes |

Comment: why are you tagging with Oracle when the question is about teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some Window Functions plus CASE like this:

```
case 
       -- If reason code is starts with "RQT"
  when first_value(Rscode) over (partition by custid order by enter_date) = 'RQT'
       -- and any of the valid code is followed By RQT
   and lead(Rscode) over (partition by custid order by enter_date) = 'RQT' then 'No'

       -- If two dates difference is <=6 moths and reason code is valid then new column value should be "Yes" other wise "No"
  when enter_date <= add_months(lag(enter_date) over (partition by custid order by enter_date), 6)
   and valid = 'Yes'
    then 'Yes'

  else 'No' -- also covers: For first row, New column value should be always "No"
end
```

Comment: Thank You so much its working but if RQT is followed By RQT than New column should be "NO" but new column showed  "Yes" , in second criteria, I replaced BCB with RQT and tested it. the new columns showed "Yes" for second row.

Comment: My query returns exactly the result you specified for you example data. If there's another issue you should add more details.

Comment: Yes your correct given query is working fine for the specified example data , I added new example (custid 346) under criteria 2.

Comment: Works for 346, too, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8f7fae

Comment: Sorry I  gave wrong example data and i made one change in the data for custid 346, I am getting new column value as "NO" for forth row if the fifth row is "RQT".

Comment: What's the logic behind `Yes` in row #4?

Comment: I don't have logic for row #4, In the example mentioned only expected result.